# Activeadmin - Need to add two values and show it in third column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am trying to add the values and introduce a new column in Activeadmin, so that when I add the values it automatically sum up the values and show it in the next column.

Image for reference:
[image: image is here]

Comment: Do you wanna add sponser fee + visa and medical to stafff salary?

Comment: No Sravan, Staff Salary + Visa and Medical = [New column]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a title to a column add add the required columns to it.

```js
index do
  selectable_column
  column "New Column" do |your_model_name|
    staff_salary.to_i + visa_&_medical.to_i
  end
end
```

[Refer here.](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html)